# How to merge histogram bins (edges and counts) by bin-count condition?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, histogram, nested-loops, binning

**The Problem**

I have a histogram of data that I would like to manipulate. More specifically, I would like to merge bins whose counts are less than a given threshold. This might be clearer with an example.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(327)

data = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=10, size=100).astype(int)
edges = np.arange(0, 101, 10).astype(int)
counts, edges = np.histogram(data, edges)

# print("\n .. {} DATA:\n{}\n".format(data.shape, data))
# print("\n .. {} EDGES:\n{}\n".format(edges.shape, edges))
# print("\n .. {} COUNTS:\n{}\n".format(counts.shape, counts))
```

The `print` commands above will output the following if not commented out:

```
 .. (100,) DATA:
[67 46 47 32 59 61 49 46 45 72 67 51 41 37 44 56 38 61 45 45 42 39 49 55
 32 35 52 40 55 34 52 51 39 55 50 62 47 43 48 39 53 54 75 38 53 44 46 39
 50 49 31 46 55 64 64 52 41 34 32 33 58 65 38 64 37 47 58 43 49 49 50 57
 71 44 41 39 47 51 47 63 55 52 43 43 49 65 48 43 44 38 64 49 62 41 40 67
 47 55 57 54]


 .. (11,) EDGES:
[  0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100]


 .. (10,) COUNTS:
[ 0  0  0 19 38 26 14  3  0  0]
```

Notice that `counts` suggests that `data` contains a single peak.  Suppose I chose a bin threshold `threshold=5` such that any bin containing less than `5` counts (`0, ..., 4` counts; not including `5`) is merged with the *next* bin. Here, *next* is taken to be in the direction towards the central peak.

**Desired Output**

By my desired merging algorithm, I would obtain the following output:

```
edges = [30, 40, 50, 60, 80]
counts = [19, 38, 26, 17]
```

**Attempt at Solution**

Below is my incorrect attempt at solving this problem:

```
def agglomerate_bins(edges, counts, threshold):
    condition = (counts >= threshold)
    indices = {}
    indices['all'] = condition
    indices['above'] = np.where(condition == True)[0]
    indices['below'] = np.where(condition != True)[0]
    # merge left-side bins rightward
    left_edges = [edges[0]]
    left_counts = []
    ileft, istop = indices['below'][0], indices['above'][0]
    while ileft < istop:
        cc = counts[ileft]
        while cc < threshold:
            ileft += 1
            cc += counts[ileft]
        ee = edges[ileft]
        left_edges.append(ee)
        left_counts.append(cc)
        ileft += 1
    # merge right-side bins leftward
    right_edges, right_counts = [], []
    iright, istop = indices['below'][-1], indices['above'][-1]
    while iright > istop:
        cc = counts[iright]
        while cc < threshold:
            iright -= 1
            cc += counts[iright]
        ee = edges[iright]
        right_edges.append(ee)
        right_counts.append(cc)
        iright -= 1
    # group modified bins with bins above threshold
    middle_edges = edges[indices['above']].tolist()
    middle_counts = edges[indices['above']].tolist()
    mod_edges = np.array(left_edges + middle_edges + right_edges[::-1])
    mod_counts = np.array(left_counts + middle_counts + right_counts[::-1])
    return mod_edges, mod_counts

mod_edges, mod_counts = agglomerate_bins(edges, counts, threshold=5)
# print("\n .. {} MODIFIED EDGES:\n{}\n".format(mod_edges.shape, mod_edges))
# print("\n .. {} MODIFIED COUNTS:\n{}\n".format(mod_counts.shape, mod_counts))
```

The `print` commands above will output the following if not commented out:

```
 .. (7,) MODIFIED EDGES:
[ 0 30 30 40 50 60 60]


 .. (6,) MODIFIED COUNTS:
[19 30 40 50 60 17]
```

Comment: The "central peak" is ambiguous in general, but not for your one example. What if there are N peaks? I mean, suppose for your example counts variable, you have a 4 after the last 3. What should you do with the 3, move it left or right? What about if you add the same number which is the max after the 3 instead? What if you have alternating 1, 10, 1, 10 with threshold of 5?

Comment: If a bimodal distribution had two central peaks with no valley inbetween, I think this method should still work. Otherwise, you are correct (since there is more than one order-dependent way to merge bins).

Comment: Probably thinking through what you truly want to achieve (play with these examples a bit on paper with respect to your goal) there's likely a set of specific rules that you can formulate that cover all cases. If you always merge to the right for example, then it's sort of like you're "accumulating" values into the bin by expanding until it meets the threshold, then you make a new bin. To that end, using a cumulative sum function seems productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a solution involves iterating through the counts and edges consolidating counts and removing 'unused' edges.  This catches [ ..., 1,2,3,...] => [..., 6, ...].  `counts` and `edges` are converted to lists which allows unwanted items to be easily popped, this isn't efficient with np.arrays.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(327)

data = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=10, size=100).astype(int)
edges = np.arange(0, 101, 10).astype(int)
counts, edges = np.histogram(data, edges)

def combine_edges( counts, edges, threshold ):
    max_ix = counts.argmax()
    c_list = list( counts )   # Lists can be popped from
    e_list = list( edges )    # Lists can be popped from

    def eliminate_left( ix ):
        # Sum the count and eliminate the edge relevant to ix
        # Before the peak (max_ix)
        nonlocal max_ix
        max_ix -= 1         # max_ix will change too.
        c_list[ix+1]+=c_list[ix]
        c_list.pop(ix)
        e_list.pop(ix+1)

    def eliminate_right( ix ):
        # Sum the count and eliminate the edge relevant to ix
        # after the peak (max_ix) 
        c_list[ix-1]+=c_list[ix]
        c_list.pop(ix)
        e_list.pop(ix)

    def first_lt():
        # Find the first ix less than the threshold
        for ix, ct in enumerate( c_list[:max_ix] ):
            if ct < threshold:
                return ix  # if ct < threshold return the index and exit the function
        # The function only reaches here if no ct values are less than the threshold
        return -1  # If zero items < threshold return -1

    def last_lt():
        # Find the last ix less than the threshold
        for ix, ct in zip( range(len(c_list)-1, max_ix, -1), c_list[::-1]):
            # ix reduces from len(c_list)-1, c_list is accessed in reverse order.
            if ct < threshold:
                return ix
        return -1  # If no items < threshold return -1

    cont = True
    while cont:
        # Each iteration removes any counts less than threshold
        # before the peak.  This process would combine e.g. counts of [...,1,2,3,...] into [..., 6, ...]
        ix = first_lt()
        if ix < 0:
            cont = False   # If first_lt returns -1 stop while loop
        else:
            eliminate_left( ix )

    cont = True
    while cont:
        ix = last_lt()
        if ix < 0:
            cont = False   # If last_lt returns -1 stop while loop
        else:
            eliminate_right( ix )

    return np.array( c_list ), np.array( e_list )

c, e = combine_edges( counts, edges, 5)

print( c, '\n', e )
# [19 38 26 17] 
# [  0  40  50  60 100]

cts, edgs = np.histogram(data, e)

print( cts, '\n', edgs )
# [19 38 26 17] 
# [  0  40  50  60 100]
```

This feels clumsy so there may be a better way but it does work.  Does it handle consecutive items less than the threshold as required?

**Edit** To answer the comment on how the `first_lt` works. The comments in the code above have been updated.

Alternative implementation with only one return.

```
def first_lt():
    result = -1  # Set default
    for ix, ct in enumerate( c_list[:max_ix] ):
        if ct < threshold:
            result = ix  # If ct < threshold set result to ix
            break        # Break out of the loop
    return result
```

`first_lt` with print statements to show what is happening as it's executed.

```
def first_lt():
    print('first_lt:',end='  ')
    for ix, ct in enumerate( c_list[:max_ix] ):
        print(ix,ct, end=': ')
        if ct < threshold:
            print('Return ix.')
            return ix
    print('Exiting loop, return -1')
    return -1
```

Comment: The solution does work for the dataset in my problem (using `np.random.seed`). Although your solution works, I cannot make sense of one loop you have used twice - one in `first_lt()` and one in `last_lt()`. The function has a `return` statement inside the `for`-loop and also in the outer scope; I do not understand how/why this works. Can you please explain what this is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the current histogram `hist` and bins `bin_edges` are returned by `np.hist()` function, and we want to merge small bins (i.e., the value of `hist` is smaller than some threshold) to larger ones, the code is shown below, where inputs are current hist and bins, and outputs are the new ones.

```py
def merge_hist_bins(hist, bin_edges, \
    hist_value_thred = 1, # i.e., 1% if is_percentile True;
    is_percentile = False
    ):
    total = np.sum(hist)
    if is_percentile:
        hist_thred = int(total*hist_value_thred*0.01)
    else:
        hist_thred = int(hist_value_thred)
    print ("[***] hist_thred = ", hist_thred)
    assert len(hist) == len(bin_edges) - 1
    bin_dict = {}
    i_rightmost = 0
    for i in range(0, len(hist)):
        if i < i_rightmost:
            continue
        edge_left = bin_edges[i]
        j = i
        tmp_hist_sum = 0
        while tmp_hist_sum < hist_thred and j < len(hist):
            tmp_hist_sum += hist[j]
            j += 1
            edge_right = bin_edges[j]
        else:
            bin_dict[(edge_left, edge_right)] = tmp_hist_sum
        i_rightmost = j
    
    idx = 0
    new_hist = []
    new_bin_edges = [bin_edges[0]]
    for k , v in bin_dict.items():
        new_hist.append(v)
        new_bin_edges.append(k[1])
        print ("key {} : {}".format(k, v))
        idx += 1
    print ("[***] done, hist_thred = ", hist_thred)
    print ("[***] old bin # = {}, new bin # = {}".format(len(bin_edges), len(new_bin_edges)))
    return np.array(new_hist), np.array(new_bin_edges), hist_thred
```

We will show the histogram with the following function:

```py
def show_hist(bin_edges, hist, fig_file = None):
    d_min = bin_edges[0]
    d_max = bin_edges[-1]
    d_num = len(bin_edges)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()  #create figure and axes 
    plt.hist(x=bin_edges[:-1], bins=bin_edges, weights=hist) 
    plt.xlabel('Value')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.title('My Very Own Histogram')
    # Figure size in inches (default)
    plt.text(x=0.5, y=0.5, \
        s=r'$D_{min}=$'+"{}".format(d_min) + r', $D_{max}=$'+"{}".format(\
            d_max) + r', $D_{num}=$'+"{}".format(d_num), 
        transform=ax.transAxes)
    if fig_file:
        plt.savefig("./results/{}.png".format(fig_file))
        print ("saved ", "./results/{}.png".format(fig_file))
    plt.show()
    txt_fn = "./results/" + npz_file + ".csv"
    comment = "#right_bin_edge, hist_value"
    file_lists = [ "{},{}".format(i, j if j > 50 else 0.5) for (i,j) in zip(bin_edges[1:], hist)]
    file_lists = [comment] + file_lists
    write_to_file(txt_fn, file_lists)
```

See the histogram before [image: histograme before merging]

and after

[image: histograme after merging]

the bin merging. In this example, input hist bin # = 256, new hist bin # = 95, with the threshold being `12%` of `sum(hist)`.

See the complete code and notes at [here](https://github.com/ccj5351/studynotes/blob/master/stereo-matching/merge_depth_bins.py).

Comment: See the complete code and code notes at this [link](https://github.com/ccj5351/studynotes/blob/master/stereo-matching/merge_depth_bins.py).